# Printing from Firefox add-on SDK?

Tags: firefox, printing, firefox-addon, add-on

Is it possible to print from the Firefox add-on SDK? I have browsed the add-on SDK online docs, but can't seem to find anything about this.

What I would like to do is to retrieve some data from a web page (a PDF file stored in a Javascript variable), and then open the system printer dialog with the file.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-on SDK doesn't have any built-in functionality for printing. Of course you can do a lot using [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html), e.g. given a browser window you can get the [`nsIWebBrowserPrint` interface](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/dcf6e5163e63/embedding/browser/webBrowser/nsIWebBrowserPrint.idl) for the currently opened window and print it:

```js
var browserPrint = browserWnd.gBrowser
                             .contentWindow
                             .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                             .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebBrowserPrint);

browserPrint.print(null, listener);
```

But the problem is still that you need to open a web page in browser in order to print it. The browser doesn't open PDF files however, this is done by a plugin - and only the plugin (that the browser has no access to) can print it. You can look in the direction of [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) but it is still in early development stages.

[`page-worker` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-worker.html) looks like an obvious way to load the page into a hidden window so that it can be printed. Only problem - to get to `nsIWebBrowserPrint` you would need to access the page's `window` object from the add-on (*not* the content script, it doesn't have the necessary privileges).

Comment: Well, actually I **am** using pdf.js loaded with script tags -- so I have the PDF file (via AJAX) in a Javascript binary array in the page. But obviously I can't send that to a printer. So what I was thinking, was to build a small add-on, that could receive the array holding the PDF file, and print it using OS print API under the assumption that the OS can print a PDF file. Does this make sense?

Comment: The OS cannot print the PDF file - the PDF reader can (Acrobat Reader, Foxit Reader and others). Rather than trying to figure out how to talk to it, it would make more sense to create a hidden `<xul:browser>` element somewhat, load your PDF data into it along with `pdf.js` and print the way I explained it above.

Comment: Yeah you're prolly right Wladimir. But the very purpose of all this was to avoid the Adobe Reader plugin. It's terrible in Firefox/Linux, and non-existing on Mac OS/X.. Similar story with the Chrome internal PDF renderer. It sucks on Linux at best.